# Creating a Hot Potato game with collections

Tags: java, collections

> Hot Potato Game: In this program you are expected to implement a
>   general simulation of the Hot Potato game. In this game children line
>   up in a circle and pass an item from neighbor to neighbor as fast as
>   they can. At a certain point in the game, the action is stopped and
>   the child who has the item (the potato) is removed from the circle.
>   Play continues until only one child is left. In your implementation
>   user should input a list of names and a constant num. Your program
>   must return the name of the last person remaining after repetitive
>   counting by num.

*I needed to do that but i couldn't find out how to stop that while loop in the* `enqueuer()` *method of hotpotato class. If i have some other mistakes can you please tell me?*

hotpotato class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class hotpotato
{
    private static Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static NodeQueue<String> potato = new NodeQueue<String>();
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int num;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter names of the children.");
        enqueuer(input1.next());

        System.out.println("Enter the num");
        num = input.nextInt();

        potatothrower();
    }


    public static void enqueuer(String p)
    {
        String keyboard = input1.next();
        while(!keyboard.equals("stop"))
            {
            potato.enqueue(p);
            }
    }

    public static void potatothrower()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< num; i++)
        {
            if(!potato.isEmpty()){
                String tmp = potato.front();
                potato.dequeue();
                potato.enqueue(tmp);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Queue is empty");
            }
        }
        potato.dequeue();
    }

}
```

Node Class:

```
public class Node<E> {
  // Instance variables:
  private E element;
  private Node<E> next;
  /** Creates a node with null references to its element and next node. */
  public Node() {
    this(null, null);
  }
  /** Creates a node with the given element and next node. */
  public Node(E e, Node<E> n) {
    element = e;
    next = n;
  }
  // Accessor methods:
  public E getElement() {
    return element; 
  }
  public Node<E> getNext() { 
    return next;
  }
  // Modifier methods:
  public void setElement(E newElem) { 
    element = newElem; 
  }
  public void setNext(Node<E> newNext) {
    next = newNext; 
  }
}
```

NodeQueue Class:

```
public class NodeQueue<E> implements Queue<E> {
  protected Node<E> head;
  protected Node<E> tail;
  protected int size;   // number of elements in the queue

  public NodeQueue() {  // constructs an empty stack
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    size = 0;
  }

  public void enqueue(E elem) {
    Node<E> node = new Node<E>();
    node.setElement(elem);
    node.setNext(null); // node will be new tail node
    if (size == 0)
      head = node; // special case of a previously empty queue
    else
      tail.setNext(node); // add node at the tail of the list
    tail = node; // update the reference to the tail node
    size++;
  }


  public E dequeue() {
    if (size == 0)
      System.out.println("Queue is empty.");
    E tmp = head.getElement();
    head = head.getNext();
    size--;
    if (size == 0)
      tail = null; // the queue is now empty
    return tmp;
  }

  public int size() { return size; }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
  }

  public E front() {
    if (isEmpty()) System.out.println("Queue is empty.");
    return head.getElement();
  }

  public String toString() {
    Node<E> temp = head;

    String s;
    s = "[";

    for (int i = 1; i <= size(); i++){
        if(i==1)
            s += temp.getElement();
        else
            s += ", " + temp.getElement();
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }

    return s + "]";
  }

}
```

Queue interface:

```
public interface Queue<E> {  
 /** 
  * Returns the number of elements in the queue.
  * @return number of elements in the queue.
  */
  public int size();  
 /** 
  * Returns whether the queue is empty.
  * @return true if the queue is empty, false otherwise.
  */
  public boolean isEmpty(); 
 /**
  * Inspects the element at the front of the queue.
  * @return element at the front of the queue.
  * @exception EmptyQueueException if the queue is empty.
  */
  public E front(); 
 /** 
  * Inserts an element at the rear of the queue.
  * @param element new element to be inserted.
  */
  public void enqueue (E element); 
 /** 
  * Removes the element at the front of the queue.
  * @return element removed.
  * @exception EmptyQueueException if the queue is empty.
  */
  public E dequeue(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call:

```
System.out.println("Enter names of the children.");
enqueuer();
```

You're doing the read data only once and then enters an infinite WHILE loop because you have no way to write "stop". Therefore the function would be:

```
public static void enqueuer()
{
    String p;
    do {
        p = input1.next();
        if (!p.equals("stop"))
           potato.enqueue(p);
    } while(!p.equals("stop"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really easy, just look better at your code:

```
public static void enqueuer(String p)
{
    String keyboard = input1.next();
    while(!keyboard.equals("stop"))
        {
        potato.enqueue(p);
        }
}
```

You get the new input before the while. This means that keyboard will be the first argument, say Alice.

So, while alice != stop, do potato.enqueue.(p).

But since you get no new input inside the while, keyboard will ever be != then stop!

Bonus:

There is a bug i think:

```
public static void enqueuer(String p)
{
    String keyboard = input1.next();
    while(!keyboard.equals("stop"))
        {
        potato.enqueue(p); //you dont insert the keyboard value, but you insert every time p!
        }
}
```